# Renew ssl for multiple cas server

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, exchange-2010

Having 2 database servers and 2 cas servers.How to  generate and renew ssl certificate on cas servers the domain name is same ex:cas.domain.com.

I have applied the certificate on one but the same cert do not go on other cas server

Comment: You need to export it from the server you have installed it on, then install on the other server using the EMC or EMS

Comment: we only have ems hosted exchange can you please tell me the steps..would be great

Answer (score 1):

The following steps will allow you to export the install certificate and import to the one or more CAS Servers.

1) Connect EMS and enter `Get-ExchangeCertificate` to list the currently installed certificates. Make a note of the thumbprint for the certificate you wish to export

2) Enter the following command

```
$file = Export-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint xxxxxx -BinaryEncoded:$true -Password (Get-Credential).password`
```

replacing the `xxxxxx` with your thumbprint from step 1. This will also prompt you to enter a password to secure the PFX you will create next

3) Enter the following command

```
Set-Content -Path "C:\somepath\mycert.pfx" -Value $file.FileData -Encoding Byte
```

Again replace the details for path to your own values

4) To import the certificate enter the following certificate

```
Import-ExchangeCertificate -FileData ([Byte[]]$(Get-Content -Path C:\somepath\mycert.pfx -Encoding byte -ReadCount 0)) -Password:(Get-Credential).password
```

Enter the password that used in step 2

You will now find that the certificate is installed and you use in it in the normal way.

Comment: thanks wat i did is export the cert as pfx from personal store and imported on other cas server on exchange sheel

 Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint DHVHEFUE838R3R83R3R93 -Services "IMAP, POP, IIS, SMTP"